# Query Ruby core documentation with ri, then display HTML in web browser?

Tags: ruby

I want to do the analog of `ri Array#join` but read it, nicely formatted, in my web browser. I know about `ri -f` but according to `ri --help`, HTML is not one of the supported format. This is with ruby 2.4.3 installed with rbenv.

Comment: What do you mean by 'nicely formatted'? You can make a wrapper script which builds a simple HTML page and opens the browser, but I'm not sure that's what you're looking for.

Comment: That's the question: how do I get the HTML?

Comment: Depending on your `RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS` rbenv may already have created a `doc` directory inside `~/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3` which you can use to browser the HTML locally. If not just `cd` in the directory and do `rdoc .`

Comment: There was no `doc` folder there. Following your advice, I did `rdoc -r html` from within the `2.4.3` directory. I don't get nowhere near the information available from `ri` though. For example, `doc/Regexp.html` only documents `json_create`, `as_json` and `to_json`!! There is still some missing dark magic. Moreover, I still don't know how `ri … Array#json` could open the right html file at the right place.